# How does time translational invariance and linearity imply irreducible solutions?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, symmetry, coupled-oscillators

The author of the book [THE PHYSICS OF WAVES](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-03sc-physics-iii-vibrations-and-waves-fall-2016/syllabus/MIT8_03SCF16_Textbook.pdf) has mentioned on page 69, at the start of second last paragraph, that

> ***The point is worth repeating: Time translation invariance and linearity imply that we can always find irreducible solutions, (3.67), in which all the degrees of freedom oscillate with the same frequency.***

I searched a lot of books and websites to understand the reason behind this but could find a satisfactory answer. I understand the concept of invariance and linearity, but the author has used a very specific kind of solutions (*on page 11, equation 1.38*), which he called **irreducible solutions**.

I don't understand why does time translation invariance and linearity imply those particular solutions.

Any help or resource will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your not going to find it elsewhere because Georgi is introducing the idea in this book, which as he says in the intro, he hopes to convert the reader to his way a viewing wave phenomena.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the author (Howard Georgi) is saying is that the derivation of the form of an irreducible solution in 1 DoF did not use the fact that there was on one degree of freedom. Therefore, the derivation applies to a system with $N$ coordinates.

Linearity means that if $z(t)$ is a solution to the equations of motion, then:

$$ h \times z(t) $$

is also solution, where $h$ is some number, which we eventually decide is $\in\mathbb{C}$.

Time translation invariance means we can shift our clock by $a$:

$$ t\rightarrow t+a $$

and our solution satisfies:

$$ z(t) \rightarrow z(t+a) = h(a)z(t) $$

He then shows that:

$$||h(a)|| = 1$$

Putting it all together:

$$ h(a)= e^{-i\omega a}$$

This is significant.

We know the solution is:

$$ z(t) = Ae^{-i(\omega t+\phi)}$$

which we are taught to think of as an oscillating solution in which the acceleration is proportional to, but in opposition to, the displacement, which we implement as:

$$ x(t)\equiv \Re(z(t))=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$

However, since:

$$ z(t+a) = Ae^{-i(\omega (t+a)+\phi)} = e^{-i\omega a} Ae^{-i(\omega t+\phi)} = h(a)z(t)$$

we can think of it as:

$$ z(t)=z(0+a)=h(t)z(0)$$

That is, the system is described by a state vector (in a 1D space) with some constant amplitude and an initial phase factor:

$$ z(0) = Ae^{-i\phi}$$

with time evolution being a simple phase factor:

$$h(t) = e^{-i\omega t}$$

The time evolution and initial state vector were required to solve:

$$[m^{-1}k-\omega^2]A=0$$

Since $A$ is just a number, that required that the frequency describing time evolution satisfy:

$$\omega^2 = \frac k m $$

So...when moving to a system of $N$ oscillators, the system is still described by state vectors, $\vec A^{(i)}$, and special frequencies, $\omega_i$, that satisfy:

$$ [{\bf M}^{-1}{\bf K}-\omega_i^2{\bf I}]\vec A^{(i)}=0 $$

which is an eigenvalue equation with $N$ solutions (degeneracies notwithstanding).

Each combination of configurations $\vec A^{(i)}$ describe the normal modes of the system, oscillating at eigenfrequency $\omega_i$.

The key insight from time-invariance and linearity condition (the original eq 1.68), is that the coordinate displacements that go into the normal modes must all oscillate at the same frequency (and in phase). That is simply not obvious if you look at the system as $N$ coupled oscillators with $N$ solutions all oscillating at combinations of different frequencies and phases:

$$ x_i(t) =ce^{-i\omega t+\phi}+ c'e^{-i\omega' t+\phi'}+c''e^{-i\omega''t+\phi''}+\ldots$$